# Посчитать кол-во одинаковых элементов в списке, прочитанном из БД

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sex FROM list_of_users")
sex = cursor.fetchall()
q_ty_sex = len(sex)
print(sex)
print(q_ty_sex)
```

Необходимо посчитать кол-во значений

```
cursor = database.cursor()
collections.Counter(cursor.execute("SELECT sex FROM list_of_users"))
sex = cursor.fetchall()
q_ty_sex = len(sex)
print(sex)
print(q_ty_sex)
```

Или я что-то не понял?

```
counter = collections.Counter(cursor.execute("SELECT sex FROM list_of_users"))
print(counter)
```

Вот traceback:

```
D:\Minicanoda3\python.exe "D:/perforce/Social/group VK API.py"
Результат: Counter()
```

Похоже, я не очень понимаю, синтаксис

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sex FROM list_of_users")
data = cursor.fetchall()
q_data = len(data)
print(data, len(data))
```

Ответ python:

```
D:\Minicanoda3\python.exe "D:/perforce/Social/group VK API.py"
[('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('1',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('1',), ('2',), ('1',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',), ('2',)] 72
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, что должно произойти

Comment: Я поправил, получилось Counter()

Comment: Так в этой колонке есть значения

Comment: что Counter(data) показывает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эффективнее будет сделать это на стороне БД:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT sex, count(*) as cnt FROM list_of_users GROUP BY sex")
```